# Tensorflow 2 graph mode - For loop in a model train_step() function?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

I am struggling to make a loop work in a model train_step() function in graph mode.

=====> Please jump directly  to UPDATE below

The following snippet, which works in eager mode but not in graph mode, is not my train_step() code but if someone could explain how to make it work when the decorator is uncommented, I think it will help me to complete my train_step().

```
import tensorflow as tf

# @tf.function
def fct1():
    y = tf.constant([2.3, 5.3, 4.1])
    yd = tf.shape(y)[0]

    for t in tf.range(0, yd):
        if t == 1:
            return t

print(fct1())
```

======  UPDATE =======

It turned out that the snippet above did not capture the **"TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"** I have at the *for* line. Please ignore it.

To reproduce my problem please run the following working code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
@tf.function
def fct1():
    yd = tf.constant(5, dtype=tf.int32)
    for t in range(yd):
        pass
fct1()
```

then add the following 3 lines of code in a working train_step() whose model is compiled with  run_eagerly=False:

```
yd = tf.constant(5, dtype=tf.int32)
for t in range(yd):
   pass
```

and get the error:

File

"D:\gCloud\GoogleDrive\colabai\tfe\nlp\translators\seq2seq_bahdanau_11\seq2seq_bahdanau_lib.py", line 180, in train_step
for t in range(yod):

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The conclusion seems to be that using the decorator @tf.function to enable the graph mode does not behave the same way as using the run_eagerly parameter of the model.compile() :

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()],
    run_eagerly=False,
)
```

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is already given by the error message:

```
NotImplementedError: in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-4-de1646e99a23>", line 8, in fct1  *
        for t in tf.range(0, yd):

    NotImplementedError: a return statement cannot be placed inside this TensorFlow loop;
        this may happen if a return statement depends on a static Python condition such as
        a hyperparameter
```

tf.function does not allow to place a return statement within a loop.  I am not a total expert on this issue, but usually it is difficult to apply all the known Python logic and you have to specifically fit it to the requirements of the graph mode (as can be seen in the error message). Your example is therefore, in my opinion, not very well chosen, because I do not get, what you actually intend to do.

You can easily rewrite the function in such a way, that it returns the same output with the decorator applied:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def fct1():
    y = tf.constant([2.3, 5.3, 4.1])
    yd = tf.shape(y)[0]
    out = 0
    for t in range(yd):
        if t == 1:
            out = t
    return out

print(fct1())
>>>tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

Actually I would be hesitant to use for-loops within a tf.function unless you are sure, that they are the way to got, but with no information about the actual task, I can only guess.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, my snippet did not represent well what I want to do. My problem is that in my real code I have a "TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" at the for line.  The tf.Tensor(5, shape=(), dtype=int32) is not accepted in the range(). Though, I can see that it works in your code. I will post the real code in case you see the problem. This is a step of a translator using seq2seq bahdanau attention. Each word of the target language has to be entered separately. Hence the loop.

Comment: I have a "TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"  but please note that in your code yd is also a tensor ! And you don't have this error in non eager mode.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this could be solved by storing the required values in a tensor array (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) instead of trying to return the values from an iterating loop. I tried to use a tensorarray by writing in an array with the required values to return as a tensor list.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys


@tf.function
def fct1():
    y = tf.constant([2.3, 5.3, 4.1])
    ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
    id = 0

    for t in tf.range(0, tf.size(y)):
      if t == 1:
        id += 1
        ta.write(id-1, t)
    return ta

print(fct1())
```

Comment: Thanks Saran, I will investigate a TensorArray solution if I don't find a less heavy solution.